# How often must I use autodiscover with Exchange?

Tags: exchange-2010, autodiscovery, exchange

As the titles states, how often should I perform an autodiscover query against Exchange? This is for a project in C# that is using Exchange Web Services (EWS).

Surprisingly enough, I can't seem to find an answer that says you should perform this every *n* hour, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on what you're doing, why you're doing it, and what constraints you have... doesn't it?

That said, since 2007, [the default autodiscovery interval for Outlook clients is an hour](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgoldman/archive/2007/10/11/what-is-the-default-refresh-rate-for-autodiscover.aspx).

I'd start there and adjust as needed.